# Why converting list into set in Cython does not work?

Tags: python, list, set, cython

What I want to achieve is to convert `list` into `set` and returning the result:

```
cpdef list_to_set(list huge_list):
    cdef list ids
    cdef set final_ids=()
    for ids in huge_list:
        final_ids.update(set(ids))

    return final_ids
```

I call it like this:

```
from core import list_to_set
.
.
.
list_to_set.list_to_set(list(dataframe['ids'].values))
```

I get the below error:

```
TypeError('Expected set, got tuple',)
```

Why should it be a tuple and why it expects a set not a list, as I've been sending a list?

---

**EDIT 1:**

To simple the problem I used the below function and got the same error:

```
list_to_set.list_to_set([[12,14], [5,6]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` is a tuple literal; type declaration and the type of the actual value do not match. You need to use `set()` instead:

```
cdef set final_ids = set()
```

Comment: It usually takes around 19 seconds to turn a list into set! Isn't there a way to improve it?

Comment: @AlirezaHos, You can change `final_ids.update(set(ids))` to `final_ids.update(ids)` because `set.update` accept any iterable.

Comment: I should have mentioned that `final_ids` is a list of sets so changed it to `cdef list final_ids = []` and then add sets into this list.

Comment: @AlirezaHos, Could you post another question with updated content?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196017/why-converting-list-into-set-in-cython-takes-so-much-time

Comment: I've posted it into a separate question, thank you for the time :)